# Editing deleted comments fails on Android app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, deleted-comments

(I apologize in advance if this is more of a feature enhancement than a bug.)

When choosing to edit a comment, I can still see my original, and I'm able to delete it while I'm editing. (I haven't tested, but I might even be able to choose to edit the original comment while I'm already in the process of editing it...?)

When I try to post the edit after deletion has occurred, it simply fails to post at all.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Post a comment to a question/answer.
2. Click your comment and choose to edit it. Your comment text should appear in a text entry field, but your original comment remains visible.
3. Click the original comment and delete it.
4. Attempt to post your edited comment. It will fail because the comment could not be found.

It could easily be resolved by:

- using a separate form as with questions/answers,
- hiding the original comment text to prevent its deletion while editing, or
- silently posting a new comment with the edit text if the original comment was deleted.

I'd prefer one of the latter two resolutions if possible as it allows one to easily refer back to the question/answer/comment.

I suppose a possibly more complicated option might be removing the edit and delete options from the menu for that comment while the comment is being edited.

SE app version: 1.0.4.8
Android 4.3
Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Comment: this is status-bydesign , once a comment is deleted it is not possible to edit it or undelete it

Comment: I understand that, but I guess I don't understand why the app displays the "Editing comment" message after it has been deleted. Either hide the comment to prevent deletion while editing in some way or perhaps add a check to ensure the comment still exists, silently posting a new one with the edited text if it does not exist, would be preferable over allowing such behavior to continue.

Comment: Please include necessary information: Stack Exchange version, Android version, and (optional) Device model. Somehow I got different behavior when I tested it just now (1.0.49 alpha): Posting the edited comment will fail silently. Btw, I prefer to just close the "editing box" when it's deleted.

Comment: @AndrewT. Post edited to include version info. I, too, experience the silent failure after the "Editing comment" message disappears. BTW I agree with the "just close the 'editing box'" bit, but by mistake I deleted my post whilst editing it. It was my intent to replace a comment that was accidentally submitted too early, preferably before anybody saw it and drew their own conclusions when I hadn't explained something fully.

Comment: Include that info ("fail silently" and "close the editing box when it's deleted") on your question body. The clearer the info, the better :)

Comment: This is a good find. I think I'm going to make it so if a comment is deleted while the edit UI is visible, the edit UI goes away.

Comment: @Kasra  did you have chance to look into it?